# How do I make this table using <table>, <tr>, <td> and <div> tags?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make the following table, but I'm having a bit of difficulty with figuring out which elements to use when. At the moment, this table has been implemented using `table` tags with the first row being done using `tr` and `td` tags.

The real problem is Cells E, F, G and H. I thought it would be possible to have the rectangular area created by Cells E, F, G and H be implemented using two `div` tags, but that doesn't seem to be working. Also, it doesn't appear like I can put a `<table>` within a `table` tag.

[image]

Comment: Use the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes of the `<td>` element.

Comment: You can try having Row2, I and J with two rowspans and h in the 3rd row with 3 colspan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Row 2</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>G</td>
        <td rowspan="2">I</td>
        <td rowspan="2">J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">H</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77a3V/

`rowspan` and `colspan` are your friends.

Comment: I think you beat me by 20 seconds.

Comment: Amazing how sometimes the simplest things get the most upvotes.

Comment: @kingjiv I have a small addendum to my question. I want to increase the space between lines so that each line is separated by 4 pixels. I only want this change to be present for Cell 'I'. I tried using line-height in CSS, but that seems to affect the entire row.

Comment: @gobias as long as you put the `line-height` only on the `td` it should only affect that cell.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/77a3V/5/

Answer (score 2):

You actually would need to use 3 rows to get this structure. Use the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes.

"A" would get a `colspan` of 2, "H" would get a `colspan` of 3.  "I and "J" would get a `rowspan` of 2.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, this should get you exactly what you have

```
<style>
td{
      border: 1px solid;  
      padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
      width: 50px;
     }

.red {
 background-color:red;   
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

<table>
    <thead/>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="yellow">
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td colspan="2">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="red">
            <td rowspan="2">Row 2</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td rowspan="2">I</td>
            <td rowspan="2">J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="red">
            <td colspan="3">H</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/63LZW/

Answer (score 1):

You think i wouldn't want to do stuff like this after doing it all day.... :)

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrod/AXCae/